# How to set jupyter notebook not to add a blank line when merging cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

By default when merging cells in jupyter notebook, one extra blank line will be inserted so that the original cells are separated by blank lines in the newly merged cell. I found this annoying because I want to make the code in the new cell concise. So I always end up removing these blank lines manually. Is it possible to configure the notebook not to include these blank lines when merging cells?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you can't.

The long answer is Yes, you can by creating your own extension and rebinding the keyboard shortcut (assuming you use the shortcut), or add a button/menu item with what you like to do. Rebind a shortcut it trivial by going to the help menu and "Edit keyboard shortcuts" once your extension is written.

The documentation to create extensions is unfortunately lacking, and one of the best resource is the [contrib-repo](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) that provide many of the extensions.
[here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/834b75af70da13eb591061dba4c49a78a90d1a17/notebook/static/notebook/js/actions.js#L509-L546) are were the merge command are defined and [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js#L1750-L1800) is the core of the merge logic. I'm pretty sure a PR adding an option to this function to tell with what to join the cell would be accepted. Then your extension "just" need to expose the right functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can. I suppose you are using Anaconda3 on Windows 10.

Go to 'C:\Users\JohnSmith\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\notebook\js'
or whereever Anaconda3 is installed and open 'main.min.js' file.
Find a function named 'Notebook.prototype.merge_cells' and there must be two 'contents.join('\n\n')' statements. 
You can edit both of them from '\n\n' to '\n'.
The first one applies to merge code cell with another code cell or markdown cell.
The second one applies when you merge two markdown cells.

This is effective after you close Jupyter Notebook application and re-start it.